# Add terminal commands with Cloud 9 plugin

Tags: shell, plugins, terminal, cloud9-ide

I'm creating a plugin for Cloud 9. It will be used for managing files in a specific way (based on my workflow).

I wanted to interface with it using shell commands (from the terminal). However, I couldn't figure out how a plugin can register shell commands. **How would I go about making my plugin register shell commands?**

Note that Cloud 9 does have [commands](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/commands), but they are only used in menus and between plugins, not in the terminal (as far as I can tell)

Comment: If I can't figure this out, I'll just stick with file and context menus

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible for a plugin to be loaded into `c9` cli tool https://github.com/c9/core/blob/master/bin/c9.
You can create independent command, and put it into a folder on PATH, 
or if you need it to run as `c9 ...` create an issue on github.

Comment: I was hopping there was a nice API for plugins to register commands then add a callback function, to be run when the user enters that command. I'm obviously a bit new to bash. Would it be possible to create something like this?

Comment: there is no api, if you could describe what do you want to do in more detail, i could  tell you how to implement it

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I found [this article](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/11/scripting-with-node/) which describes how you can add commands using a Node package. I was hoping that C9 plugins could do this, but I don't mind just using Node.